# UIbutton with ControlEvents not working on uitableviewcell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

This is my code

```
UIImageView *bgDetails = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 47)];
bgDetails.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bgDetail"];

UIButton *btnLike = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnLike setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"38_38"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btnLike.frame = CGRectMake(278, 4.5f, 37, 37);
[btnLike addTarget:self action:@selector(doLike:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[bgDetails addSubview:btnLike];
[cell.contentView addSubview:bgDetails];
```

But `btnLike` does not call the `doLike` method. Please help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible issues here. The first one is this: I'm not sure whether it's just a typo, but you write

```
action:@selector(doLike:)
```

but then later you complain about the selector `doLike` which does not have the trailing colon (i. e. it takes no arguments). If this is the problem, you can fix it by changing either one, so that the two selector names match (they both need to be `doLike:` or `doLike`, consistently).

The other error I see is that you're adding the button as a subview of an image view. `UIImageView` has user interaction turned off by default, so in order it to react to user touches, you have to set its `userInteractionEnabled` property to enabled:

```
bgDetails.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```